# NoSQL with Pubsub

Tags: nosql, publish-subscribe

I'm currently looking at an architecture where I need to utilize a pub-sub system and a NoSQL data-store and instead of using two different products I'm wondering if there are any good products that support both storage and pub-sub.

> What are the current available stable NoSQL data-stores that also
>   support the publish subscribe pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out Redis.

http://redis.io/commands

Quite a lot of people seem to use it for messaging and pub/sub and it has a solid reputation as a key/value store as well.

It definitely has a ton of traction in the NoSQL world these days.